# Synchronizing my Eclipse CVS Branch with the Head

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I'm working on a "branch" in Eclipse .

Some changes were commited on the "HEAD" branch.

How can I easily update my branch so that it can be synchronized with the HEAD ?

Thank you

PS:

What I did, but I'm not sure it's the best method, is :

- I commited my changes to the branch I'm working on
- Right Click > Switch to another branch or version ... > Head (It puts the HEAD in place of my branch)
- Right Click > Merge ... (Then I select where I merge the HEAD and here I choose my branch).
- Finally, I : Right Click > Switch to another branch or version ... > My Branch
  and here I get my branch

Is there a cleaner way to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "right-click" -> "update".

Comment: So what is the difference between "update" and "synchronize with repository" ?

Comment: "Update" is somewhat automatic.  "Sychronize" gives you more flexibility.  See this: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-113.htm.

Comment: -1: That's only going to update the local branch from the repository branch.

Comment: @Steve11235: Yes, and that's the first step in doing a merge (which is what the OP appeared to be interested in).

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do it is to right click on the project in the branch and select Team->Merge.
Merge the changes done in HEAD with the branch using the Tagging concept.